# Кастомный Switch с подписями

Tags: jquery, css, button, animate, switch

Есть Switch с подписями, при клике на сам switch он должен переключаться, так же переключение может происходить при клике на значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.switch input {
  display: none;
}
.switch {
  width: 45px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #00cc8c;
  transition: .3s;
}
.slider:before {
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  background-color: #008f62;
  transition: .3s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #f8ee7c;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #f8ee7c;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
.slider.br {
  border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.br:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider br"></div>
</label>
```

Возможно подключение jQuery. Сама изюминка вопроса в добавлении активных надписей "Вкл/Выкл"

https://fiddle.jshell.net/w4t05476/

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Как такой переключатель реализовать?

Comment: а что есть на данный момент? или только какая-то картинка? _Как такой переключатель реализовать?_ html+css, html+css+js как-то так

Comment: это не сайт готовых решений. Тут помогают с вашим кодом, так что напишите, что у вас уже есть,  и что не работает. Если еще ничего нет, то сначала попробуйте решить свою задачу, а потом обращайтесь за помощью.

Comment: @СергейБондаренко За вас здесь ничего делать не будут. Если сами не способны реализовать хоть часть, наброски какие-то => вам к фрилансерам.

Comment: Ну осталось только указать цену и сроки

Comment: Накастомить [это](https://pepelsbey.net/2012/08/stylish-switch/) и добавить текст по сторонам + парочка обработчиков. Нашлось за 5 секунд в гугле.

Comment: Тю, что вы взъелись на меня, наработка конечно есть. Вообще сама изюминка вопроса заключается в добавлении к переключателю надписей "Вкл/Выкл". https://fiddle.jshell.net/w4t05476/

Comment: вся необходимая информация должна быть непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: Мы не взъелись, просто вопрос прозвучал как "сделайте мне" =) Добавьте, пожалуйста, Ваш fiddle в вопрос

Comment: Да, все же не правильно вопрос составил

Comment: Ну дык изюминку надо обозначить, а не список требований городить. А что мешает до/после добавить по `<span>`, и туда вбить вкл/выкл? Ну или прикрепить через jQ

Comment: Что добавить <span> или подключить jQ на словах я тоже знаю. Я обратился сюда потому что уже перепробовал различные варианты,  ничего не получилось

Comment: _уже перепробовал различные варианты, ничего не получилось_ - вот и стоило добавить эти варианты, и пояснить, что именно не получилось

Comment: при нажатии на активный ВКЛ - должен ли отключиться?

Comment: при нажатии на активный ВКЛ - должен ли отключиться? нет, не должен. если активный "Вкл" то срабатывает только "Выкл" и наоборот

Comment: [Подойдёт](https://jsfiddle.net/755k24bq/)?

Comment: Более чем! Спасибо. Выкладывайте в ответ на подтверждение правильного результата

Comment: @СергейБондаренко готово

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**:

```
.selector-on {
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selector-off {
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.switch input{
    display:none;
}
.active-selector {
  color: #00cc8c;
}
.switch{
    width: 45px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.slider{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #00cc8c;
    transition: .3s;
}
.slider:before{
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-color: #008f62;
    transition: .3s;
}
input:checked + .slider{
    background-color: #f8ee7c;
}
input:focus + .slider{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #f8ee7c;
}
input:checked + .slider:before{
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
.slider.br{
    border-radius: 34px;
}
.slider.br:before{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<span class="selector-on active-selector">On</span>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox">
  <div class="slider br"></div>
</label>
<span class="selector-off">Off</span>
```

**jQuery**:

```
function enableDisable(flag) {
  $('.my-checkbox').prop('checked', flag);
  $('.selector-on').toggleClass('active-selector', function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('active-selector') ? true : false;
  });
  $('.selector-off').toggleClass('active-selector', function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('active-selector') ? true : false;
  });
}
$('.selector-on').on('click', function(event) {
  return $(this).hasClass('active-selector') ? false : enableDisable(false);
});

$('.selector-off').on('click', function(event) {
  return $(this).hasClass('active-selector') ? false : enableDisable(true);
});

$('.my-checkbox').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('.selector-off').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.selector-on').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/755k24bq/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').before('<span id="label_before">On</span>').after('<span id="label_after" class="label_active">Off</span>');
$('input[type=checkbox]').onchange(function(){
    $('#label_before').toggleClass('label_active');
    $('#label_after').toggleClass('label_active');
})
```

Это если имеет смысл добавлять элементы через jQ. Я бы предпочел сразу все в html вставлять/через пхп генерить, не знаю, как там завязано у Вас все, но так не красиво, да и работает в идеале с одним свитчем.

Код не тестировался, работоспособность не гарантируется. Гарантируется только смысл.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.b-switch {
  margin: 15px 35px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  width: 55px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
  
  background-color: #00cc8c;
  border-radius: 35px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 70px);
  height: 100%;   
  cursor: pointer;  
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-color: #008f62;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label > span,
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label + span{
   position: absolute;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding: 0 5px;
   color: #008F62;
   font-weight: 600;   
   cursor: pointer;
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label > span{
  right: 100%;
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  background-color: #f8ee7c;  
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  left: calc(100% - 26px);
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label > span,
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"] + label + span{
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;  
}
.b-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span{
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="b-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch">
  <label for="switch">
    <span>Вкл</span> 
  </label>
  <span>Выкл</span>
</div>
<div class="b-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-2">
  <label for="switch-2">
    <span>Вкл</span> 
  </label>
  <span>Выкл</span>
</div>
<div class="b-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-3">
  <label for="switch-3">
    <span>Вкл</span> 
  </label>
  <span>Выкл</span>
</div>
```